# Книги для изучения визуального программирования в Java

Tags: java, книги

Для изучения самого джава я сейчас читаю Шильдта. А какую книгу вы мне можете посоветовать для изучения оконного программирования в джава? С какого начинали вы?

Comment: Шильдта тебе хватит

Comment: А как после него перейти на визуальное программирование?  В Шильдте разве это описано? @Gorets

Comment: Оконное программирование не самая сильная сторона Java - посоветую сконцентрироваться на web/database сторону

Comment: QtJambi никто не пробовал?

Comment: @navi1893, прислушайтесь к совету @Barmaley. Мне вот из этой области SmartGWT понравился, на самом деле красивые картинки получаются.

Answer (score 2):

[Название: Swing: Руководство для начинающих
Автор: Герберт Шилдт](http://vipbook.info/pk/programing/24223-SHildt-Gerbert-Swing-Rukovodstvo-dlya-nachinayushc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Расскажу вам свою историю.

4 месяца недавно пересел на технологию Oracle ADF (jDeveloper). До этого всю жизнь специализировался на php и все, с чем он связан, а в последние два года Node.JS.

Только сейчас закончил первое свое приложение, которая работает с базой данных и веб-сервисами, т.е. 4 месяца потратил на изучение этого самого jDevelopera. Мое мнение на текущий момент таково - в технологиях Java для веб-разработки, по крайней мере ADF, с другими не знаком, слишком большой уровень абстракции от веба.

Они постарались свести веб-разработку к разработке десктопных приложений, а это совсем разные области. Многие вещи делаются перетягиванием мыши, т.е. декларативно, за счет чего выигрывает куча времени.

Однако оставшееся количество приходится делать очень извращенными способами. Плюс отсутствие документации, плюс абсолютно другая терминология, сложности деплоя, настройки сервера и в итоге выйграное время вначале слихвой тратится на эти вещи. Учился на oracle titorials, блоги, youtube и т.д... 95% всего - на английском языке. Никаких книг не читал. Сам по себе Java - довольно легкий и интуитивно понятный язык.

Но я еще в начале пути, много чего еще не видел и мнение всегда смогу поменять. )

Comment: интересная история для клуба аннонимных программистов :) вот только это не джава свела разработку под дестоп. а вообще это такая идея разработки, причем если я не ошибаюсь начиналась с asp -  разграничить веб морду от логики и по возможности свести верстку к удобному виду, что диктовалось потребностью делать динамический контент на страницах

Answer (score 0):

[Язык программирования Java](http://computersbooks.net/index.php?id1=4&category=language-programmer&author=arnold-k&book=1997)
Автор: Арнольд К.